# How to forcefully end filter-chain in an early servlet/spring boot filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session, spring-filter

Having a multi-tenancy application, I want to end any request without a tenant very early.

## Setup / Scenario

I run spring boot (web) with spring session and spring security.

In my case, I have several strategies to determine the tenant, TenantFromX, TenantFromY .. all running on order `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` - so as early as possible.

On order `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+1` I run the `TenantMustExistFilter` filter to validate, that any strategy actually did match / find a tenant definition

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
// After TenantFromX(min) but before SessionRepositoryFilter(Session) which is min+50
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public class TenantMandatoryFilter extends GenericFilterBean
{
  @Override
  public void doFilter(
    ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    if (TenantStore.getInitMode().isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoTenantException("No tenant identified for request - request blocked");
    }

    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
      TenantStore.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

## Question / Problem

Eventhough I throw an Runtime exception `NoTenantException` all other filters after that filter are called anyway.

For example `SessionRepositoryFilter` is called on `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+50` and then the spring security `FilterProxyChain` is triggered.

How do I effectively stop the chain after `TenantMandatoryFilter` has failed to validate?
I expected either a `return;` or and `Exception` or just not calling `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` to be just enough to end the chain execution.

Do I have a misunderstanding of the process or the idea here?

## Attempts

I can successfully end the chain by replacing

```
if (TenantStore.getInitMode().isEmpty()) {
  throw new NoTenantException("No tenant identified for request - request blocked");
}
```

with

```java
if (TenantStore.getInitMode().isEmpty()) {
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
  return;
}
```

Interestingly the below will not work, even though it seems semantically more correct. It does not work means, it will call the `SessionRepositoryFilter` and the `FilterChainProxy` after that nevertheless.

```java
if (TenantStore.getInitMode().isEmpty()) {
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid tenant");
  return;
}
```

Which I assume is since `sendError` sets the response to suspended to complete any other chain (which is what I do not want).

It still does not seem right, so **how to do this the right way?** Or is this a conceptual flaw altogether?

Comment: I understand i could replace the exception with `response.reset();response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);response.flushBuffer();return;` which would actually stop the chain. Using `response.reset();response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);response.flushBuffer();return;` interestingly does not do that (because of the suspend). Still it all feels wrong conceptually.

Comment: Sending an error, either via an explicit call or by throwing an exception, will cause the request to be dispatched to the application’s error page handling which will invoke the filters again for that dispatch. Setting the status is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you @AndyWilkinson - i understand. So an exception would later rather be processed by `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and `sendError` by the error Page handler, which comes late also. If you like, just answer the question and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thank god I found your question, I've been scratching my head for days without no clue why my filter chain kept being called even though I wasn't calling `doFilter` in the chain object. Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending an error, either via an explicit call or by throwing an exception, will cause the request to be dispatched to the application’s error page handling which will invoke the filters again for that dispatch. Setting the status is the right thing to do.